# How to create overlapping bar charts in angular js?

Tags: angularjs, highcharts, chart.js

i have trying to create a chart like [image]

this. I have tried with highchart.js and chart.js but result is not like expected. Is there any plugin to create a chart like this? Or any other way to stack like this in highchart.js or in chart.js? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use highcharts [Fixed placement columns](https://www.highcharts.com/demo/column-placement) that is inverted. Check the demo posted below.

HTML:

```
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<div id="container"></div>
```

JS:

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
  chart: {
    type: 'column',
    inverted: true
  },
  xAxis: {
    categories: [
      'Seattle HQ',
      'San Francisco',
      'Tokyo'
    ]
  },
  yAxis: [{
    min: 0,
    title: {
      text: 'Employees'
    }
  }, {
    title: {
      text: 'Profit (millions)'
    },
    opposite: true
  }],
  legend: {
    shadow: false
  },
  tooltip: {
    shared: true
  },
  plotOptions: {
    column: {
      grouping: false,
      shadow: false,
      borderWidth: 0
    }
  },
  series: [{
    name: 'Employees',
    color: 'rgba(165,170,217,1)',
    data: [150, 73, 20],
    pointPadding: 0,
    groupPadding: 0.15,
    pointPlacement: 0
  }, {
    name: 'Employees Optimized',
    color: 'rgba(126,86,134,.9)',
    data: [140, 90, 40],
    pointPadding: 0.2,
    pointPlacement: 0
  }]
});
```

Demo:
https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/g0b9uev5/1/

Comment: Thank you. This is what I'm looking for.